# Introducing the Woodworking Pro Tem Moderators

Tags: discussion

For every newly launched SE site, we need members who focus on helping with community-building issues and site management. That's why we select a few members from each community to act as temporary, provisional Moderators. You can read about the program here: [**Moderators Pro Tempore**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

I am pleased to announce that these members have stepped up and generously volunteered their time to help us ensure that the community's issues are properly addressed.

[image: CRSouser]
[image: Jan Murphy]
[image: PolyGeo]

We want to make this site a huge success, and these members are great examples of exactly the type of people we need to make this site succeed.

#### Did I overlook anyone?

Almost certainly. There are members who are actively involved and very deserving of recognition. My failure to account for everyone this early on is in *no way* a slight against them. One of the best things about Stack Exchange sites is that there are lots of opportunities to contribute and help lead, with or without a diamond -- *mods can't do it alone!*

Most of all, please be respectful and understanding of the Moderators Pro Tem. Members of your community are volunteering their time and learning on the job. We're all in this thing together.

Comment: Congrats to you three!

Comment: Thanks! I don't want to put words in anyone else's mouth, but I'm pretty sure I'm also speaking for bowlturner, drs, and probably everyone here when I say everyone has been doing a great job starting up and running WW.SE thus far. I'm happy to help grease the gears as-needed to keep things rolling smoothly. Keep up the great work, everyone!